# How can I make auto-complete display a list in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, autocomplete

How can I use auto-complete in Xcode like I can in Visual Studio and Eclipse?  Specifically in VS and Eclipse auto-complete displays a list of choices... while Xcode just displays a single choice.

For example Xcode might suggest "myVariable" when I type in "myV".  That's fine but what if I have the following objects in the scope of my function:  "myInt1" and "myInt2"?  Xcode will suggest "myInt1" when I type "myI" but I'd like to have a list.  Or it would be great to, say, tab through the various possibilities like in some shells.  So typing "myI" would get the suggestions "myInt1" and then pressing tab would change the suggestion to "myInt2".

Cheers!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Press the escape key when auto-complete makes the first suggestion.  This will display the list.

Comment: +1 I'll vote that up, it took me a few days to figure that out when I started

Comment: Escape or control-comma will show the list, control-period will accept the current suggestion and (subsequently) rotate through suggestions, control-slash will move to the next placeholder argument that was inserted. Control-shift-slash and control-shift-period move to previous placeholder and rotate through suggestions in the opposite direction, respectively.

Answer (score 42):

`control + space` also works in the latest Xcode.

Comment: Isn't this also shortcut for language input switch?

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski Yes, it is. I recommend remapping language input switch to something like  `^⌥Space` (in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources`)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xcode > Settings > Key bindings and search for "Show completions":
[image]

From here, you can change the shortcut to be whatever you want (I use cmd + space).