# Autocompletion in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make auto-complete display a list in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954320/how-can-i-make-auto-complete-display-a-list-in-xcode)

I'm just learning Objective-c and how to use Xcode, coming from a background of Python. In python, when using the interactive prompt, you can do something like this:

```
list = []
list.**tab**
```

pressing tab displays all the methods one can do on the list, like append things, et cetra.

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like this in Xcode, as it would save me a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954320/how-can-i-make-auto-complete-display-a-list-in-xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hit the <kbd>esc</kbd> key and it'll show you list of methods. Also, typing will generally bring up some suggestions when Xcode believes there are matches.

Comment: XCode 4 also added support for ctrl+space

Comment: Cool edit using kbd.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called code completion, and it's available in Xcode. When you start typing, Xcode will try to find the most likely completion and will display it in light colored text. Press tab to accept the offered text, or escape to get a list of other possible completions. You can of course customize the keys to your liking. Check the Xcode documentation for [a complete description of how completion works](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CompletingCode/CompletingCode.html).